# Bulk import of .json files in arangodb with python

Tags: python, document, arangodb

I have huge collection of .json files containing hundreds or thousands of documents I want to import to arangodb collections. Can I do it using python and if the answer is yes, can anyone send an example on how to do it from a list of files? i.e:

```
for i in filelist:
    import i to collection
```

I have read the documentation but I couldn't find anything even resembling that

Comment: Have you see this ? https://www.arangodb.com/tutorials/tutorial-python/

Comment: I don't know much about ArangoDB, but you should also check the [Python ArangoDB driver documentation](https://python-driver-for-arangodb.readthedocs.io/en/master/document.html#documents) for an example of using the `collection.import_bulk()` method to insert multiple documents in bulk. I would suggest, depending on how your files are structured, that you loop through them and create a list of documents you want to insert to a collection then call `import_bulk()`. Depending on how many there are you might need to batch the insertion.

Comment: GiovaniSalazar. Yes I started from there and I couldn't find any examples on file import. They only have examples on document import

Comment: Mihai Chelaru. I have also seen what you propose. the problem is that nowhere I can find any examples for file importing. there is only bulk document importing. My problem is that every file I have is a bulk import for collection and I have a huge bulk of files for each collection. So what I need is bulk file import because even with bulk import of documents i would have to do file by file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after a lot of trial and error I found out that I had the answer in front of me. So I didn't need to import the .json file, I just needed to read it and then do a bulk import of documents. The code is like this:

```
a = db.collection('collection_name')
for x in list_of_json_files:
    with open(x,'r') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
        a.import_bulk(data)
```

So actually it was quite simple. In my implementation I am collecting the .json files from multiple folders and importing them to multiple collections. I am using the python-arango 5.4.0 driver

Comment: I am getting an error that my collection has no attribute 'import_bulk'. What version of ArangoDB are you using?

Comment: The latest version. Did you install the python-arango driver?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem.  Though your implementation will be slightly different, the answer you need (maybe not the one you're looking for) is to use the "bulk import" functionality.

Since ArangoDB doesn't have an "official" Python driver (that I know of), you will have to peruse other sources to give you a good idea on how to solve this.

- The [HTTP bulk import/export](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/http/bulk-imports.html) docs provide `curl` commands, which can be neatly translated to Python web requests.  Also see the section on [headers and values](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/http/bulk-imports-importing-headers-and-values.html).
- ArangoJS has a [bulk import](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/drivers/js-reference-collection-bulk-import.html) function, which works with an array of objects, so there's no special processing or preparation required.

I have also used the [arangoimport](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/3.6/programs-arangoimport.html) tool to great effect.  It's command-line, so it could be controlled from Python, or used stand-alone in a script.  For me, the key here was making sure my data was in [JSONL](http://jsonlines.org/) or "JSON Lines" format (each line of the file is a self-contained JSON object, no bounding array or comma separators).