# How can I import JSON files

Tags: python, arangodb

I have a problem. I have several `JSON` files. I do not want to create manually `Collections` and import these files. I found this question [Bulk import of .json files in arangodb with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61345323/bulk-import-of-json-files-in-arangodb-with-python), but unfortunately I got an error `[OUT] AttributeError: 'Database' object has no attribute 'collection'`.

How can I import several `JSON` files and import them fully automatically via Python in `Collections`?

```py
from pyArango.connection import *
conn = Connection(username="root", password="")

db = conn.createDatabase(name="test")

a = db.collection('collection_name') # <- here is the error
for x in list_of_json_files:
    with open(x,'r') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
        a.import_bulk(data)
```

I also looked at the documentation from `ArangoDB` https://www.arangodb.com/tutorials/tutorial-python/

Comment: You haven't posted enough code, what is `db` ?

Comment: don't know much about arangodb but it seems you already load each JSON as a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

There is no "collection" method in db instance, which you try to call in your code on this line:

```
a = db.collection('collection_name') # <- here is the error
```

According to docs you should use db.createCollection method of db instance.

```
studentsCollection = db.createCollection(name="Students")
```